# Apply where condition when I have multiple rows for each id (Single table or Join multiple ones)

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have below requirement in mysql/SQL Server

```
Table Name: basic(pid int,av int,sid int,st int,wid int,wt int)
```

For each pid, there would be 10 rows (containing sid,st values and wid,wt values for each pid). These sets could be from 1 to 10.

So, for a pid value (example: 3213 and 3214), there will be 10 rows like below

[image]

Like the above, there could be millions of records

What am trying to achieve is, I want to get the pid's whose (sid=2 and respective st>=7) and also whose (wid=9 and respective wt>=6)

If I apply this condition, I should get list of pid's which must have two pid's 3213 and 3214.

How can I achieve this using simple sql query or i can divide the table into three like basic1(pid,av), basic_sk(pid,sid,st) and basic_wc(pid,wid,wt)

since I can use pid as reference, I can join .. even I tried using joins, and couldn't achieve the required result.

I used below join -

```
select t1.pid from basic1 t2
inner join basic_sk t2 on t1.pid=t2.pid
inner join basic_wc t3 on t3.pid=t2.pid
where (((t2.sid=2) and (t2.st>=7)) and ((t3.wid=9) and (t3.wt>=6)))
```

but no luck.
How about if I have multiple sid and st values in where condition and wid and wt values..
like in sets {sid=2,st>=7} and {sid=4,st>=9}
and {wid=9,wt>=6} and {wid=5,wt>=5}

How can I achieve my requirement using simple sql query ?

Any possibility is fine for me, with one table or multiple tables (using join)

Comment: You should decide which database you are using (MySQL or SQL Server) and tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation and a having clause;

```
select b.pid
from basic b
group by p.pid
having sum(case when (b.sid = 2) and (b.st >= 7) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when (b.wid = 9) and (b.wt >= 6) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the rows that match each condition.  The `> 0` ensure that there is at least one row for each.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for the query!  How about performance point of view, if we use this query on one table which has millions of rows.. and how if we divide that into three tables and fetch the result set. Which one will be more faster do you think?

Comment: @SathishPanduga . . . I don't know; you would need to test on your data in your environment to determine which is faster.